# How can I fix the vulnerability CVE-2021-3449?

Tags: 22.04, docker, nodejs, vulnerability

I have installed nodejs package (version `18.16.1-deb-1nodesource1`) on Ubuntu `22.04`. Trivy vulnerability scan identified `CVE-2021-3449`. It is related to OpenSSL version `1.1.1` to `1.1.1j`. But the OpenSSL version installed on Ubuntu is 3. How can we fix this CVE so that it won't come up in Trivy scan?

Comment: Ask whoever sold the broken CVE scanner to you to fix it

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/security/cves?q=CVE-2021-3449 & https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-3449

Comment: On closer inspection, nodejs on Ubuntu 22.04 is at [`12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/nodejs), which is nothing like the version you have specified. It seems you got it from somewhere other than the official repositories. In that case, ask the source of this package to fix it.

Comment: I think you might be referring to Node 12 version. I have installed the node 18 from NodeSources from https://github.com/nodesource/distributions. For Node 18, 18.16.1 is the latest version.

Comment: @noonenine so that's not from Ubuntu, now is it? You should be asking nodesource for the patched release.