# What is meant by needed in Ubuntu CVE status?

Tags: 22.04, nodejs, vulnerability

In the below link, the status of the CVE shows `needed` for nodejs and jammy. What does it mean?

https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-3449

Answer (score 1):

It means that the Ubuntu Security Team has determined that a patch for the `nodejs` package in Ubuntu 22.04 is needed, but has not done so yet.

This is common for newly-disclosed vulnerabilities (that CVE was published less than 24 hours ago). Note that the OpenSSL and PostgreSQL portions of the CVE have already been patched and uploaded. You are seeing a work still in progress.

HOWEVER, in a previous question, [How can I fix the vulnerability CVE-2021-3449?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1474736), your `nodejs` package version suggested that it didn't come from Ubuntu. You got it from elsewhere. The Ubuntu Security Team CVE tracker and patches apply ONLY to correct-version packages in the Ubuntu repositories...which your output strongly suggests that you don't have.